# Layout for personal branches in TFS

Tags: tfs, branch, tfvc

Recently we migrate from SVN to TFS and have next layout:

```
$
  Project
    Main
      Project
    Branch
      Branch1
      Branch2
```

Now I want add folder for personal branches and try to choose layout for this. Currently I think about:

```
$
  Project
    Main
      Project
    Branch
      Branch1
      Branch2
    Private
      Smith, John
        my-personal-branch
      Doe, John
        huge-refactoring
```

(folder 'Private' on same level as 'Branch' with subfolders for each user)

I fear that this layout can has some drawbacks, which I don't see because my poor expirience in TFS.

I appreciate any suggestions/examples.

Comment: It's sensible to a level of the sensibility of personal branches. It's probably better to have a set of **Feature** branches, if you need long-term isolation. getting rid of these long-term branches is probably your best solution. If you want quick and easy you should consider Git on TFS instead of TFVC.

Comment: We can't use Git, it is company policy :(

Comment: Use Git-tf and have local branches ;)

Comment: I will try, but later. I want learn TFS as much as possible to be able to compare it with SVN/GIT. BTW, I try git-svn and was not very satisfied. We have big project and git was not so fast as I expected.

Comment: Reading the ALM Rangers' version control guidance is a good thing to do. Then trying to stay as much on the main line even better ;).

Comment: Avoid branching at a personal level (to me thats an overkill), this introduces a ton of work to merge all these changes back together, especially when the latest code needs to shared among everyone. Instead combine features which are going out to Prod together and then use a single DEV branch (like Branch1, Branch2) for that, which will be shared by all the developers working on that project/feature. This will save a lot of time for everyone.

Comment: Isaiah4110, we use personal branches for some dangerous experiments which can't be included in current development branch. We has no problems with merges in SVN and hope will so in TFS.